# Does windows have a limit on the number of UVC extension unit commands

Tags: uvc

everyone. Recently, I was developing a method to access the camera extension unit through windows and send commands through the interface "ksproperty". There was a problem. Commands 0x01-0x19 can be sent normally, but commands 0x20 and above failed, and the error code 0x80070490 was returned. Is this a limitation of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a limitation of usbvideo.sys.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/device-requirements-for-usb-video-class-extension-units